# ArgMin for vector<double> in C++?

Tags: c++, collections, stl, vector

I'd like to find the **index** of the minimum value in a C++ `std::vector<double>`. Here's a somewhat verbose implementation of this:

```
//find index of smallest value in the vector
int argMin(std::vector<double> vec)
{
    std::vector<double>::iterator mins = std::min_element(vec.begin(), vec.end()); //returns all mins
    double min = mins[0]; //select the zeroth min if multiple mins exist
    for(int i=0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        //Note: could use fabs( (min - vec[i]) < 0.01) if worried about floating-point precision
        if(vec[i] == min)    
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

(Let me know if you notice any mistakes in the above implementation. I tested it, but my testing is not at all exhaustive.)

I think the above implementation is probably a wheel-reinvention; I'd like to use built-in code if possible. Is there a one-line call to an STL function for this? Or, can someone suggest a more concise implementation?

Comment: `std::min_element` doesn't "returns all mins". It returns an iterator to the smallest element in the range. If the minimum occurs multiple times the iterator points to the first one. Your `mins[0]` should probably be `*mins` since it's an iterator, not an array of results.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could use the standard `min_element` function:

```
std::min_element( vec.begin(), vec.end() );
```

It returns an iterator to the minimum element in the iterator range. Since you want an index and you are working with `vector`s, you can then substract the resulting iterator from `vec.begin()` to get such index.

There is an additional overload for a function or function-object if you need a custom comparison.

Comment: ...then subtract the iterators to find out the index.

Comment: `std::min_element(v.begin(), v.end()) - v.begin()`

Comment: @larsmans: How crude. Sophisticated people say `std::distance(v.begin(), std::min_element(v.begin(), v.end()))` :-)

Comment: If you use std::distance, it will work even if v.begin() is not random access and has to be incremented one step at a time to get you the answer.  This may be what you want.  But you may prefer to use simple operator- so that if you are falling into a performance bug it won't compile.

Comment: It lives in `<algorithm>` - just in case someone wonders.