# Argmin for static arrays

Tags: c++, image-processing, multidimensional-array, visual-c++

Hello all I am trying to implement the **Argmin** function. following the example from one of the comments here [ArgMin for vector<double> in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667867/argmin-for-vectordouble-in-c), I have written the following logic.

```
    rev_tone = get_rev_tone(cam_model_path);
    //reading the images
    Mat img_rev = imread("C:/Users/20181217/Desktop/images/imgs/output_rev.png");
    Mat ideal = imread("C:/Users/20181217/Desktop/images/imgs/output_fwd_v6.png");
    int idx = 256;
    int no_of_channels = 3;
    float rev_tone_s[256][3];
     ///dynamic to static conversion
    for (int i = 0; i < rev_tone.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < rev_tone[i].size(); j++) {
            rev_tone_s[i][j] = rev_tone[i][j];
        }
    }
    int dist = distance(rev_tone.begin(), std::min_element(rev_tone.begin(), rev_tone.end()));//rev_tone is of type vector<vector<float>>
    cout << dist << endl;
    int dist_s = distance(rev_tone_s.begin(), std::min_element(rev_tone_s.begin(), rev_tone_s.end())); //rev_tone_s is a static 2d float of type float[256][3]
    cout << dist_s << endl;
```

when i am executing the program, this line is working without any problem.

```
  int dist = distance(rev_tone.begin(), std::min_element(rev_tone.begin(), rev_tone.end()));//rev_tone is of type vector<vector<float>>
```

But the nature of my project doesn't allow any dynamic memory allocations. so I have converted the Vectors into arrays (**`float_rev_tone_s`**). When I try to perform the Argmin() on the converted array in the following line

```
int dist_s = distance(rev_tone_s.begin(), std::min_element(rev_tone_s.begin(), rev_tone_s.end())); //rev_tone_s is a static 2d float of type float[256][3]
```

it gives me an error saying **`expression must have a class type`**. I have looked at this error and it says it was a pointer issue. My question is why is it only a problem for an array but not for vector??
According to the cppreference, `.begin()` of an array also gives the initial iterator.

Is there a way to work around this for defining Argmin() over an array?

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is why is it only a problem for an array but not for vector?

`vector` is an object, so it has member functions like `size()` and `begin()` and `end()` for iterators. While array is just a raw type, just like and `int` or a `float` and not an object, so you don't have any member functions for it.

> According to the cppreference, `.begin()` of an array also gives the initial iterator

That is correct, but that array is `std::array` which is a wrapper over raw arrays. It doesn't allocate any memory at runtime so you can and should use that. Advantage of using the `std::array` over raw array is that

- You get member functions like `size()` and iterators.
- It won't decay to a pointer whenever you pass it as an argument to a function.

Here's how you declare a 2D `std::array`:

```cpp
std::array<std::array<float, 256>, 3> arr ;
```

Note that you need to `#include <array>` for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're confusing C++'s `std::array` with C-style arrays (which is what you're using in the code you posted):

> ```cpp
> float rev_tone_s[256][3];
> ```

This is a C-style array, not a `std::array`. C-style arrays are basically raw pointers to objects of the underlying type and a pointer does not have the `begin` method. `std::array` on the other hand is an STL container which has the `begin` method.

This means you could just change the type of your `rev_tone_s` variable if you want to have stuff like STL-iterators:

```cpp
std::array<std::array<float, 256>, 3> rev_tone_s;
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. indeed i confused std::array with c style array. this solves my problem.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to invoke `begin()` on a pointer

Here is an example of using `distance` with pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

const int arr_size = 100;
float myarray[arr_size];

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arr_size; ++i) {
        myarray[i] = static_cast<float>(100 - i);
    }
    std::cout << std::distance(myarray, std::min_element(myarray, myarray + arr_size)) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```